# Thin autostart with nginx (through rvm)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, rvm, thin

I currently have different users setup with a Rails app in each users home directory. I used RVM to install separate version of Ruby, Rails, and Thin in each home directory. If I login to the user and issue:

```
thin start -e production --servers 2 -p ####'
```

then it starts fine. I have seen several methods of auto-starting Thin but most revolve around either a shared RVM being installed or a single version of Thin being installed. So far my attempts have failed so I am looking for suggestions.

**Edit**: To be clear each user account has manually installed RVM in their home directory, then gem installed specific version of Thin.

Answer (score 0):

separate installations are quite good approach that will give best separation between apps

for guide on running tasks in background check https://rvm.io/integration/cron/